# Is it possible to use a trained regression model of body tracking in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, regression, ml-agent

I have trained a model using regression with TensorFlow to estimate the human pose, continuously.
Now, I am wondering if I can use this trained regression model in unity to track the human hands and body.
I see that Reinforcement learning models are available in unity using MLAgent. Also, classification models were before used in unity.
plus, I know there are many works related to human pose estimation in unity; however, I am not sure if it is possible to use a trained model like this and estimate human body tracking in unity also?

Comment: You can use the Barracuda package to execute your model in Unity. https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.barracuda@1.0/manual/index.html

Comment: @celion Thank you for your comment. Do you know if it is also possible to use the TensorflowSharp plugin for a regression model? sorry, that I am not so familiar with unity.

Comment: I don't know much about TensorflowSharp - ML-Agents used to use it but not any more. You'd be on your own getting it set up.

Comment: @celion Okay, I see. Thank you for your helps